# Slice an Table to produce an array based on a Date Interval (Excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have the following table on an Excel sheet :

```
AN_DATE     PORT_RET     PORT_MKTVALUE 
1-Jul-15    0.04%        749,708,691.20 
2-Jul-15    0.10%        750,456,134.73 
3-Jul-15    -0.01%       750,387,777.34 
6-Jul-15    -0.13%       749,424,519.97 
7-Jul-15    -0.04%       749,093,484.64 
8-Jul-15    -0.19%       747,704,970.94 
9-Jul-15    0.11%        747,189,760.25 
10-Jul-15   0.30%        749,417,098.50
```

Is it possible to extract an array between 2 dates using formulas ? e.g. I would like a formula that would return  the PORT_RET between 7 and 10 of July, the resulting array should be (as a result on a new set of cells):

```
7-Jul-15    -0.04%
8-Jul-15    -0.19%
9-Jul-15    0.11%
10-Jul-15   0.30%
```

Comment: Why not use filter?

Comment: i want to enter the initial and end date of the interval and get the sliced array to calculate some other interval parameters that a filter wouldn't work. e.g. cumulative return on the interval on every data point. And also to update a chart based on the calculations

Comment: Then ask what you want as final outcome, with the formulas you plan on using.  You will need array type formulas, and there are good, better, best approaches depending on the final formula you want.

Comment: What i want is perfectly described. Thanks

Comment: okay then I am misunderstanding, do you want the output in new cells, from which you will apply new formulas?  Do you want the output in a form that can be used directly in another formula, without the need of helpers cells?

Comment: The issue is `array` can be interpreted many different ways.

Comment: No problem, i edited the question. The result should be an array on a new set of cells.

Answer (score 0):

Put 07-Jul-2015 in Z1 and 10-Jul-2015 in Z2, create a named range (Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager) with the following as the Refers to:

```
=index('sheet1'!$A:$B, 'sheet1'!$Z$1, 0):index('sheet1'!$A:$B, 'sheet1'!$Z$2, 0)
```

This creates a 'slice' of 'sheet1'!$A:$B equal to 'sheet1'!$A$6:$B$9.

Answer (score 0):

Put your beginning and end dates in E1:F1,  Put this in the first cell and copy down and over:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$9)/(($A$2:$A$9>=$E$1)*($A$2:$A$9<=$F$1)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

---

Now to the reason I wanted clarity,  Say you wanted the MEDIAN of PORT_RET for that range.  You could easily skip the helper cells and refer directly to the data with this array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(($A$2:$A$9>=$E$1)*($A$2:$A$9<=$F$1),$B$2:$B$9))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter.

As you can see below I got the same answer without the need of the helper columns.

[image]